# Virtual audio device installation failed with Debut

Tags: screen-capture

I am trying to use [Debut](https://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html) Screen Capture software on my Mac, but failing with the following error

[image]

Reboot doesn't help.

What can be done?

Comment: At a guess it's trying to install to some legacy location & the OS isn't allowing it; or it's 32-bit & can't run. The site says "Works on Mac OS X 10.5 and above" which is a big warning flag. I'd ask the developer.

Comment: I found this, which seems more hopeful - https://nch.invisionzone.com/topic/33959-debuts-exported-videos-wont-playback-on-macs-big-sur/?tab=comments#comment-92158 - I'd still ask the developer about it.